# Not able to keep GUI variables as global

Tags: user-interface, go, andlabs-ui

I find following code works:

```
// modified from: https://github.com/andlabs/ui/wiki/Getting-Started
package main
import ("github.com/andlabs/ui")
func makewinfn() {
    var name = ui.NewEntry()
    var button = ui.NewButton("Greet")
    var greeting = ui.NewLabel("")
    box := ui.NewVerticalBox()
    box.Append(ui.NewLabel("Enter your name:"), false)
    box.Append(name, false)
    box.Append(button, false)
    box.Append(greeting, false)
    mywindow := ui.NewWindow("MyTitle", 200, 100, false)
    mywindow.SetChild(box)
    button.OnClicked( func (*ui.Button) {greeting.SetText("Hello, " + name.Text() + "!") } )
    mywindow.OnClosing( func (*ui.Window) bool { ui.Quit(); return true } )
    mywindow.Show()
}
func main() {
    ui.Main(makewinfn)
}
```

However, if I try with global variables:

```
package main
import ("github.com/andlabs/ui")
// keeping following as global variables: 
var name = ui.NewEntry()
var button = ui.NewButton("Greet")
var greeting = ui.NewLabel("")
func makewinfn() {
    box := ui.NewVerticalBox()
    box.Append(ui.NewLabel("Enter your name:"), false)
    box.Append(name, false)
    box.Append(button, false)
    box.Append(greeting, false)
    mywindow := ui.NewWindow("MyTitle", 200, 100, false)
    mywindow.SetChild(box)
    button.OnClicked( func (*ui.Button) {greeting.SetText("Hello, " + name.Text() + "!") } )
    mywindow.OnClosing( func (*ui.Window) bool { ui.Quit(); return true } )
    mywindow.Show()
}
func main() {
    ui.Main(makewinfn)
}
```

This code with global variables compiles all right but creates following error on running:

```
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x7fecb2712e19]
```

How can I keep GUI components as global variables? I have keep them as global so that I can access them from other functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use variables at the top level (package block), they are initialized before execution of `main()` begins.

And you call code from the `github.com/andlabs/ui` package, but its `ui.Main()` was not yet called, and so the `ui` package and resources it depends on may not have been initialized.

Only declare the variables but do not yet assign values to them, leave that to the `makewinfn()` function:

```
var name *ui.Entry
var button *ui.Button
var greeting *ui.Label

func makewinfn() {
    name = ui.NewEntry()
    button = ui.NewButton("Greet")
    greeting = ui.NewLabel("")

    box := ui.NewVerticalBox()
    // ...
}
```